# Windows 10 UDP larger datagrams not received?

Tags: udp, client, datagram

Looking for advice/pointers. I have a set of functions that work receiving UDP datagrams. All work fine, interfacing with a digital mixer, sending and receiving literally 100's of datagrams per second. While most datagrans are under 100bytes, some are bigger, and receiving datagrams up to approx 4kB works fine, but anything above that is just... not received, no error, nothing reported by the recvfrom() function not the select() call it/when I use non-blocking calls. Below is a small test program that will receive with no problems the datagram corresponding to message=1 (that's a near 2kB datagram), but will hang when requesting a larger datagram (approx 20kB) after sending message=2. Note: I systematically verified that max buffer sizes in the OS are systematically 64kB or more. I tried using Windows, ubuntu 18.04 and even Mac... SAME result, with the same hang. Wireshark on the Windows system showed the bytes being all received by the NIC (24383 bytes). Tried with and without firewall.

program (nothing fancy there...):

```
/*
 * cudp.c
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 24, 2020
 *      Author: Patrick-Gilles Maillot
 *  Simple udp client
 */
#include<stdio.h>       //printf
#include<string.h>      //memset
#include<stdlib.h>      //exit(0);
#include<windows.h>

#define BUFLEN 32768            //Max length of buffer
char    buf[BUFLEN];

void die(char *s) {
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void) {
    struct sockaddr_in  Wip;
    struct sockaddr*    Wip_addr = (struct sockaddr *)&Wip;
    int                 Wip_len = sizeof(Wip);  // length of addresses

    int                 Wsocket, len;
    char                message[32];
    char*               mess;
    WSADATA             wsa;
    char                Wip_str[32] = {"192.168.1.71"};

    char mess_1[32] = {"/io/in/LCL\0\0,s\0\0*\0\0\0"};  // results in a 2kB datagram
    char mess_2[32] = {"/io/in\0\0,s\0\0*\0\0\0"};      // results in a 20kB datagram


    if (WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) {
            printf ("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( (Wsocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
        die("socket");
    }
    int iVal = 128000;
    int iSize = sizeof(iVal);
    len = setsockopt(Wsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF , (char *) &iVal, iSize);
    printf("ret code: %d, buffer size = %d\n", len, iVal);

    len = getsockopt(Wsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&iVal, &iSize);
    printf("buffer size = %d\n", iVal);

//  iVal = 10000;
//  len = setsockopt(Wsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO , (char *) &iVal, iSize);
//  printf("ret code: %d, buffer size = %d\n", len, iVal);
//
//  len = getsockopt(Wsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO , (char *)&iVal, &iSize);
//  printf("timeout = %d\n", iVal);

    memset (&Wip, 0, sizeof(Wip));                  // Clear struct
    memset((char *) &Wip, 0, sizeof(Wip));
    Wip.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Wip.sin_port = htons(atoi("2223"));
    Wip.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(Wip_str);


    while(1) {
        //request what message to send (1 or 2)
        printf("Enter message : ");
        gets(message);
        if (message[0] == '1') {
            mess = mess_1;
            len = 20;
        } else if (message[0] == '2') {
            mess = mess_2;
            len = 16;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

        //send the selected message
        if ((len = sendto(Wsocket, mess, len , 0 , Wip_addr, Wip_len)) == -1) {
            die("sendto()");
        }
        //receive a reply and print it
        //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
        memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call; if blocked... just Ctrl-c !
        if ((len = recvfrom(Wsocket, buf, BUFLEN, 0, 0, 0)) == -1) {
            die("recvfrom()");
        }
        printf("len: %i: ", len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (buf[i] < 32 || buf[i] == 255 || buf[i] == 127) printf("~");
            else                                               printf("%c", buf[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Has anyone seen/experienced similar issues/limitations? and been able to find a fix? Or maybe it's right there under my eyes, but what is it?

Thanks
-Patrick

PS: I know TCP is better etc, etc. I don't have the choice here. The server is a HW system.

Comment: Thx for getting back to me. I did push the max UDP buffer size to a larger value using:
 // set IO buffer to 512k (we'll use max 256k)
 iVal = 524288;
 len = setsockopt(Wsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF , (char *) &iVal, iSize);
and still got the problem. 
Then interestingly enough, I wrote my very own server-client code and had no issue in sending/receiving 256kB UDP buffers. So there's something in the way Windows handles packets somewhere in the network stack that makes it drop large packets.

Comment: So far, I gave up in using large buffers and have managed to break my requests into smaller chunks, not as efficient in terms of time, but probably safer knowing what can happen on larger buffers.